# Canvas - Get position of colour if available

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to get the position of a colour on canvas.

I know you can get the colour at a position like this

```
context.getImageData( arguments ).data
```

But I would like to try and find a colour in canvas, so say I would have this colour black.

```
rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

I would like to get the position of that colour if it exists on canvas, I've asked Google but I only get the **Get colour at position** which is the opposite of what I need.

Comment: when the colour is in many positions (e.g. the entire canvas is black), what would you expect it to return?

Comment: The first one it finds.

Comment: so any pixel then? assuming the order of iteration is optimal, it will find the topmost, or if that's a tie, the leftmost, if you follow Jani's answer.

Comment: Any pixel yes the first one you find that is closest to the colour it doesn't really matter what order you start doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned already you need to iterate over the pixel buffer.

Here is one way you can do it:

(**[Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/jD34b/)**)

```
function getPositionFromColor(ctx, color) {

    var w = ctx.canvas.width,
        h = ctx.canvas.height,
        data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h), /// get image data
        buffer = data.data,                  /// and its pixel buffer
        len = buffer.length,                 /// cache length
        x, y = 0, p, px;                     /// for iterating

    /// iterating x/y instead of forward to get position the easy way
    for(;y < h; y++) {

        /// common value for all x
        p = y * 4 * w;

        for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            /// next pixel (skipping 4 bytes as each pixel is RGBA bytes)
            px = p + x * 4;

            /// if red component match check the others
            if (buffer[px] === color[0]) {
                if (buffer[px + 1] === color[1] &&
                    buffer[px + 2] === color[2]) {

                    return [x, y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will return the x/y position of the first match of the color you give (`color = [r, g, b]`). If color is not found the function returns `null`.

(the code can be optimized in various ways by I haven't addressed that here).

Comment: Thanks, do you have any recommendations (not do it for me) on how I would get the closest colour as stated in the question, I can't quite work out how it's done.

Comment: @Pinocchio you can add a tolerance value and then check the components with +/- with that tolerance. F.ex. if 10% tolerance then check `if (r >= buffer[0] / 1.1 && r <= buffer[0] * 1.1 && ...)`. But to get closest, purely, you need to calculate distance vectors for each existing color and then pick the one with shortest vectors to each component.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to iterate over the `data` property and check the RGB values. Basically you would iterate in groups of 4, as each pixel is stored as 4 indices, and compare the values accordingly.

Comment: I was thinking that but what if you had a picture that was `500 x 500` would looping 62 Thousand times be really bad?

Comment: 62000? There are 250000 pixels in a 500x500 image. And you have no other option. Besides, in modern browsers where many things are compiled to machine code before running, 250000 will run fast enough as long as you're not using it too many times per frame.

Comment: +1 Since each of the 250K pixels is represented by 4 pieces of information (r,g,b,a)  you are really examining up to 1 million pieces of info.  Still, computers are fast so your pixel will be found relatively quickly.  Also, presumably you will find your black pixel before examinining all 250K and will stop there.

Comment: Well you said in groups of 4 so I divided it by 4, my bad.